# How to open Log4net logs on azure. I keep getting 404 errors

Tags: azure, http-status-code-404, azure-web-app-service, log4net

I have inherited a Azure App service that has log4Net doing the logging.  I would like to open these logs and read them.

On the azure portal I have gone to Overview\Browse and found a long list of .log files.

When I  click to open one of these files I get a 404 error. They also cant be downloaded, it just says file not found.  The files do have a file size, so I suspect they are there.

I have read something about mime file settings...?

Comment: You could use the Kudu console to traverse the file directory: http://www.jamessturtevant.com/posts/How-to-add-edit-and-remove-files-in-your-azure-webapp-using-the-kudu-service-dashboard/

Comment: Do you have any update on this thread? if it is useful, please mark it as an answer that will help more communites who have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

If we want to overview the .log file from the broswer, we could [remote to Azure WebApp](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/remote-administration-of-windows-azure-websites-using-iis-manager/) to add the [MIME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/staticContent/mimeMap) extension log MIME type text/plain to Azure IIS.

[image]

If we want to download the .log files, as Andrés Nava - .NET mentioned that you could use Kudu console(`https://{webAppname}.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`) to do that.